# Duration between workout and dinner

Tags: diet, bellyfat, timing

I am undergoing with weight training and cardiovascular exercises  these days majorly for reducing belly fat and for strengthening muscles as well . After workout i feel hungry so i immediately takes my dinner (not so heavy). Is that right to take dinner just after workout?

Comment: You *should* eat quite soon after training, but *what* to eat is important--the answer sums it up (although some will say 2:1) and IMO faster-digesting proteins would be preferred, although a mix is likely fine.

Comment: Thanks Dave Newton for putting your comment over here. I got lot of information from the article "Recovery Nutrition for Athletes"linked by Sancho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's okay to eat right away. Based on the advice from this article (*[Recovery Nutrition for Athletes](http://athletics.macalester.edu/custompages/Deno_Videos/nutrition/recovery_nutrition.pdf)*, from the NSCA's Performance Training Journal):

> It is now well established that the key to maximizing recovery is to
>   consume carbohydrates and proteins immediately after exercise.
>   Research indicates that the ideal recovery nutrition is a meal or
>   liquid supplement containing high-glycemic carbohydrates and quality
>   proteins in approximately a 4:1 ratio, that include  10 – 20% of the
>   athlete’s total daily caloric intake of these two macronutrients.

Comment: Thanks Sancho for your nice comment . I read whole article "(Recovery Nutrition for Athletes" that was quite interesting and knowledgeable.