# Best way of eating after exercise for reducing belly fat

Tags: diet, cardio, bellyfat

I have much large belly fat as compared to upper body. Daily i do weight training (45min to 1 hr) + cardiovascular (45 min). I want to make upper body muscles , simultaneoulsy want to reduce my large belly.

The questions

1 . [Do different workouts require different diets?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/912/eating-after-working-out)

2 . [How long should I wait with eating after an exercise?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/543/how-long-should-i-wait-with-eating-after-an-exercise)

3 . [Duration between workout and dinner](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/duration-between-workout-and-dinner)

The answers on above questions have made me confused to wheather take diet just after excercise or wait for long in order to reduce belly.

Answer (score 5):

IMO you should *always* eat after exercise to replenish glycogen and protein.

Waiting (or not) will not be the gating factor in determining if you lose belly fat.

Losing fat is (largely) a matter of math: expend more calories than you consume. Differences caused by specific post-working meal timing will be trivial compared to overall, long-term habits.